# Remove certain fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

So I have a box widget and a foldable widget tab that has many fields. How can I get rid of the first fields as well as other *n*-fields, which could be field 4 or 9 or 7th field?

```
<div class = "widgetPanel containerWidgetPanel foldableBox">
    <div class="boxBody">
        <table class="widgetTable containerWidgetTable">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
                  <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
                  <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td class="boldColumn containerLabel">
                  <td class="fieldColumn containerField">
               </tr>
               .....
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far... Only for the first field...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery( "tr td" ).first().remove();
     });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreicated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.eq()` - for example to remove 4th `td`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery( "tr td" ).eq(3).remove();
});
```

If you want to remove both `td`s in first row, use this:

```
jQuery("tr").eq(1).find("td").remove();
```

Comment: I assumed you achieved what you want removing first `td` and gave the method for removing `nth`  `td` - I don't know what class parameters you mean

Comment: I meant what should I write within the jQuery(   _What whould I put here_    ) ?

Comment: depends what you want to remove - if `td`, then `'td'`, if `td` with class `fieldColumn`, then your selector can be `'td.fieldColumn'`, if `tr`, then `'tr'` and so on

Comment: so then it has to be jQuery("td.containerLabel").eq(0).remove(); and jQuery("td.containerField").eq(0).remove() to remove the first field then? I tried this and it's not working... Here's what I did here...

[http://jsfiddle.net/DvGa9/41/](http://jsfiddle.net/DvGa9/41/)

Comment: yes, but to remove both `td` from the `nth` row, use the code from my edited answer.